# PHP basic (noobish) concept question: Constant vs. Function

Tags: php, performance, constants

I have a global "functions.php" file containing functions used throughout my site.

In terms of performance, efficiency, etc – is it better to call one of these functions directly or to define them as constants and call the constant instead? (Or does it matter at all?)

ie

```
<?php echo site_root(); ?>
```

vs.

```
<?php echo SITEROOT; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't obsfucate your code that way. Are you suggesting utilizing constants as names to functions? You won't see a performance gain doing this. But if your wanting to output string literals that don't change, then this is the correct use of constants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what `site_root()` does exactly.

- If all it does is something very simple like read from an array and return a string, it doesn't matter whether you use the function, or a constant. Use whatever works best for you.
- If the function does something expensive like a database lookup, it is indeed wise to do the call only once, store the result in a constant, and use that in the code.

Comment: Sorry to answer in a really old thread but I just wonder - isn't using function an overkill in comparison with just storing the value in const? Since introduction of ' const ABC = "abc" ' construction consts are way quicker that before when using define() method

Answer (score 2):

Adam, another option is to use static vars as a cache inside a function:

```
function site_root() {
    static $result = null;
    if (!is_null($result)) {
         return $result;
    }
    // code for defining and returning result only once
}
```

---

You can use constants only when your code always require them. And if your code use it only here or there, then don`t use them, as code, that will define them will slow down your main code.